# Underscore character not show in html input with font monospace

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Google Chrome the underscore character "_" is not shown in an input control with font-family monospace. Any idea why?

Any suggestions for a workaround?

[Demo here](https://jsbin.com/fowoxaz/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="test_test">
</body>
</html>
```

```
input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

The value in the demo input control is "test_test" but it displays as "test test".

Comment: It seems to happen only at certain font sizes.

Comment: I'm not seeing it... meaning, I see the underscore, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Linux. Maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Perhaps the input height is too small to see the underscore. Try to put some height and see if the problem remains. The underscore must be there for sure:)

Comment: I've done that. Still invisible.

Comment: Works fine on my chromebook. Maybe something about the monospace font on my ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 and find this problem either. The problem occurs on Chrome and Edge (chromium-based), but not Firefox. My solution is to unset height property of the input box class.

```
.form-control {
    height: unset;
}
```